# SELECT MAX(COUNT) MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL, and I have a task to do right now where I have three tables:

1. students(id,name)
2. courses(id,name)
3. grades(id, student_id (FK), course_id(FK), grade)

I am supposed to

> fetch the name of the course that is the most registered by students and if there is any conflict or ties with other course, retrieve the course after sorting ascendingly.

I tried several queries, but they are not 'efficient enough'

```
SELECT course.name FROM (
SELECT CI ,MAX(Total) FROM 
(
    SELECT course_id as CI,COUNT(*) AS Total 
    FROM grades
    GROUP BY course_id ASC
) AS Results

) AS x

INNER JOIN courses ON x.CI = courses.id
```

And

```
SELECT courses.name FROM (
SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) AS how_many
    FROM grades
    GROUP BY course_id ASC
    HAVING how_many = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS how_many
            FROM grades
            GROUP BY course_id
            ORDER BY how_many DESC
            LIMIT 1
    )
    LIMIT 1
) AS X
JOIN courses ON X.course_id=courses.id
```

Is there any more efficient query?

Comment: `course.name` is a typo for `courses.name`

Answer (score 0):

Both your query attempts look logically incorrect to me.  You should be joining `courses` to `grades` to obtain the number of students enrolled in each course.  Regarding efficiency, the `RANK` analytic function is one of the most performant options, assuming you are running MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.id, c.name, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, c.name) rnk
    FROM courses c
    INNER JOIN grades g ON g.course_id = c.id
    GROUP BY c.id, c.name
)

SELECT id, name
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can use a `LIMIT` query:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN grades g ON g.course_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, c.name
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The latest edit that added the second solution is equivalent to my solution, I don't find it fair/sportive by you.

Comment: @lemon Your answer is wrong, because the counts will always be 1, for every course.  I posted a correct version.

Comment: My answer will return every course with one instance of each student that is enrolled in the specific course. From my point of view, if the student has enrolled in a course and has given an exam multiple times, there will be multiple instances of that student for the specific course, which is something that your answer does not address as you'll be counting that student multiple times. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ORDER BY` clause with the `LIMIT` clause to get what you need, without aggregating twice:

```
WITH enrollments AS (
    SELECT course_id, COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) AS num_enrollments
    FROM grades
    GROUP BY course_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM       enrollments e
INNER JOIN courses c
        ON e.course_id = c.id
ORDER BY e.num_enrollments DESC, c.name ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The subquery will get you the enrollments by aggregating on the students,
then it is joined with the courses to use the course name.

Data is then ordered by:

- number of enrollments descendent
- course name ascendent

and only the first row is considered.

Comment: `enrollments` is the alias of the cte. In your answer the corresponding alias is `cte`. I'm assuming that every student, found in the `courses` table, has been enrolled in the course, that's the reason of that name.

Comment: The `courses` table does not have a `student_id` column.

Comment: You want to say that this answer does not work because of a typo? `courses` should be `grades`, it's true. The idea (you copied as edit) is what matters.